# Как прикрутить swiper, что бы от 300 до 600 px выводился 1 слайд от 600 до 920 2 слайда и если экран больше 920 то 3 слайда и слайдер был не активен

Tags: html, swiper

Есть блок. Как к нему прикрутить swiper слайдер, что бы от 300 до 600 px выводился олин слайд от 600 до 920 два слайда и если экран больше 920 то 3 слайда и слайдер был не активен

````
    <div class="products__container flex container swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="card swiper-slide">
      <img src="images/product.jpg" alt="" class="card__img">
      <h2 class="card__title"> REY NEGRO ARABICA </h2>
      <p class="card__description">100% Арабика </p>
      <p class="card__structure"><span class="bold">Состав:</span> кофе натуральный жареный в зернах ,средней обжарки
      </p>
      <p class="card__keeping"><span class="bold">Условия хранения:</span> хранить в сухом прохладном месте , при
        температуре не выше 27 С и относительной влажности воздуха не более 75:</p>
      <p class="card__expiration"><span class="bold">Срок годности:</span> 18 месяцев </p>
      <p class="card__weight"><span class="bold">Масса нетто:</span> 1000 гр </p>
      <p class="card__gost"><span class="bold">Гост 32775-2014</span></p>
      <div class="card__btns flex">
        <a href="#" class="card__btn oz">купить на</a>
        <a href="#" class="card__btn wb">купить на</a>
      </div>
 
    </div>
    <div class="card swiper-slide">
      <img src="images/product2.jpg" alt="" class="card__img">
      <h2 class="card__title"> REY NEGRO ARABICA </h2>
      <p class="card__description">100% Арабика </p>
      <p class="card__structure"><span class="bold">Состав:</span> кофе натуральный жареный в зернах ,средней обжарки
      </p>
      <p class="card__keeping"><span class="bold">Условия хранения:</span> хранить в сухом прохладном месте , при
        температуре не выше 27 С и относительной влажности воздуха не более 75:</p>
      <p class="card__expiration"><span class="bold">Срок годности:</span> 18 месяцев </p>
      <p class="card__weight"><span class="bold">Масса нетто:</span> 1000 гр </p>
      <p class="card__gost"><span class="bold">Гост 32775-2014</span></p>
      <div class="card__btns flex">
        <a href="#" class="card__btn oz">купить на</a>
        <a href="#" class="card__btn wb">купить на</a>
      </div>
 
    </div>
    <div class="card swiper-slide">
      <img src="images/product3.jpg" alt="" class="card__img">
      <h2 class="card__title"> REY NEGRO ARABICA </h2>
      <p class="card__description">100% Арабика </p>
      <p class="card__structure"><span class="bold">Состав:</span> кофе натуральный жареный в зернах ,средней обжарки
      </p>
      <p class="card__keeping"><span class="bold">Условия хранения:</span> хранить в сухом прохладном месте , при
        температуре не выше 27 С и относительной влажности воздуха не более 75:</p>
      <p class="card__expiration"><span class="bold">Срок годности:</span> 18 месяцев </p>
      <p class="card__weight"><span class="bold">Масса нетто:</span> 1000 гр </p>
      <p class="card__gost"><span class="bold">Гост 32775-2014</span></p>
      <div class="card__btns flex">
        <a href="#" class="card__btn oz">купить на</a>
        <a href="#" class="card__btn wb">купить на</a>
      </div>
 
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>```
````